# How can i avoid duplication in a proc append even if i run it twice?

Tags: sas, macros, append, proc

I can't just delete duplication from my base table because i have a DATETIME column so it will not be considered like duplication.

Exemple :
base (after first append) :

```
+------+----------------------------+------+-----+
| name | date                       |  id  |year |  
+------+----------------------------+------+-----+
|    X |Thursday06july2020 16:21:06 |   303| 2019| 
|    Y |Thursday06july2020 16:21:06 |   91 | 2020|  
+------+----------------------------+------+-----+
```

after doing some modification on my data table i will have this in :

```
+------+----------------------------+------+-----+
| name | date                       |  id  |year |  
+------+----------------------------+------+-----+
|    W |Friday07August2020 13:27:15 |  92  | 2019|
|    X |Friday07August2020 13:27:15 |  303 | 2019| 
|    Y |Friday07August2020 13:27:15 |  91  | 2020|  
|    Z |Friday07August2020 13:27:15 |  45  | 2020|
+------+----------------------------+------+-----+
```

then i want to reexcute the proc append.
Is there any method to compare all the columns expect the date column ?
I wish that it's clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a primary key on all of your columns except date in your base table. For example:

```
data basetable;
    length pk $50.;
    set basetable;
 
    pk = cats(name, id, year);
run;
```

You can use this to update values and columns within your data.

To continue using `proc append`, you can create an integrity constraint on `pk` that prevents duplicates on your base table.

```
proc datasets lib=mylib nolist;
    modify basetable;
        ic create unique (pk);
quit;
```

This integrity constraint will be destroyed if you recreate the table.